# InnerChannel = 'webServiceProxy.InnerChannel' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to Consume WCF Service for SSRS Reports.

I have tried to exceed the message size limit to But it gives me with the exceptions which is as follows :

```
InnerChannel = 'webServiceProxy.InnerChannel' threw an exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException'
Channel = 'webServiceProxy.Channel' threw an exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException'
```

Code to Export on Server Side to Consume WCF..

try
{

```
                var webServiceProxy = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(wcfEndpointConfigName);
```

// End Point Name is Coming here which is written in web Config file :  basicHttpEndpoint

```
                webServiceProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
               System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
                webServiceProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = clientCredentials;

                // Init Report to execute
                ServerInfoHeader serverInfoHeader;
                ExecutionInfo executionInfo;
                ExecutionHeader executionHeader = webServiceProxy.LoadReport(null, report, null,
                                                                             out serverInfoHeader, out executionInfo);

                // Attach Report Parameters
                webServiceProxy.SetExecutionParameters(executionHeader, null, parameters, null, out executionInfo);

                // Render
                serverInfoHeader =
                    webServiceProxy.Render(executionHeader, null, GetExportFormatString(format), null,
                                           out output, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings,
                                           out streamIds);
            }
            catch (FaultException e)
            {

                throw new FaultException(e.Message);
            }
```

Web Config File

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" receiveTimeout="05:00:00"
          sendTimeout="05:00:00" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://../ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportExecutionServiceSoap"
        contract="MyServiceReference.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="basicHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Can some onw guide me where I am doing wrong I been stuck into this for days.

Comment: I've used the [WCF Client tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe) extensively in the past to resolve tons of WCF issues.

Comment: Hey @reas I am using NTML authentication ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875957/how-to-test-my-endpoint-url-in-wcftestclient-exe-with-ntlm-authentication